# jquery function not working for duplicate Division

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have a function to reverse my scroll bar function using an custom element. now when i duplicate the div's i am unable to get it to work. can someone help me out in making it work for multiple divisions ??

The fiddle is here :  [JS Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/daneuchar/zHyA9/)

Any kind of help would be great.

HTML:

```
<div id="textarea">
    <div id="test">

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas eget nisi ipsum. Donec semper, justo at fringilla condimentum, felis tellus ultricies dolor, id convallis metus nulla quis est. Vivamus facilisis orci vel lectus blandit commodo blandit sem tempor. Curabitur condimentum, diam quis pretium feugiat, sem ante pretium tortor, in lobortis massa eros vitae dui. Nullam nisi mauris, condimentum a feugiat in, euismod quis augue. Maecenas euismod adipiscing tellus. Aliquam elementum egestas dolor, vel aliquam nulla tincidunt eget. Etiam risus elit, scelerisque eu volutpat sed, faucibus non ante. Donec sed nunc erat, eget facilisis risus. Etiam id odio tortor. Sed aliquam viverra volutpat. Sed gravida lectus eu mi ornare in feugiat magna elementum. Pellentesque in dolor ligula.

Maecenas condimentum nisl eget arcu elementum nec imperdiet risus lobortis. Suspendisse id placerat turpis. Etiam dolor quam, placerat et volutpat nec, ultricies sed lorem. Fusce volutpat lobortis est ut pellentesque. Donec enim mauris, pretium quis gravida vitae, pellentesque ac nibh. Proin condimentum aliquam scelerisque. Vestibulum aliquet pharetra dapibus. Donec id nisi non nibh fringilla auctor et eget erat. Morbi pretium mauris sed orci pretium aliquam. Nulla pharetra venenatis nunc, in venenatis purus tempor vitae. Vivamus tincidunt dui non eros gravida sit amet consectetur nibh lacinia. 

Maecenas semper ligula et urna tincidunt placerat. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Suspendisse arcu urna, facilisis at tempus id, posuere sed lacus. Vestibulum in feugiat tellus. Nullam suscipit, velit nec tincidunt pellentesque, enim odio ornare mauris, quis faucibus sem sapien sed turpis. Nulla sit amet risus in magna iaculis scelerisque sit amet vel erat. Morbi eu vestibulum nulla. Etiam auctor auctor felis, nec sodales velit condimentum non. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Duis eu massa diam, eu porttitor eros. Etiam blandit, turpis ac volutpat gravida, massa lorem congue orci, eget fringilla eros felis quis elit. Suspendisse quam tellus, pretium non mattis ut, laoreet in diam. Suspendisse ante odio, venenatis vel condimentum vitae, varius id sapien. Quisque ac nunc ipsum. Mauris porttitor blandit magna, id rutrum ipsum pellentesque non. In suscipit diam ligula, non tristique diam.

Aliquam interdum ante at nisl sagittis vel luctus eros fringilla. Vestibulum purus orci, ultrices at tristique et, malesuada eget enim. Praesent commodo erat vel massa auctor id elementum elit elementum. Duis diam urna, mollis ut imperdiet aliquam, commodo id dui. Etiam vulputate facilisis dui id convall

Aliquam interdum ante at nisl sagittis vel luctus eros fringilla. Vestibulum purus orci, ultrices at tristique et, malesuada eget enim. Praesent commodo erat vel massa auctor id elementum elit elementum. Duis diam urna, mollis ut imperdiet aliquam, commodo id dui. Etiam vulputate facilisis dui id convall Daniel 
        asdasdas dasd asd asldnalsdsvlkarau idhlkjansdfnl inaldnflkanlsdfh ]sdf oasdfj ihjaiodfhkajdsnoviaehu234 kn 87r 23n sf8yr 1238u ndkfn9 48yj wodifn2937rh e0o94tjo nug-2jnfio 203nf273rhefn 2893hr0 284f jnf j0nm ;onf9o8h sdjfi9 w8rho jubnr9ygv7gh wionuf2983h iurbgfi9 48hr jfna sdf asdf alsdfn a;sdf kasdfkjasdfnasdfjakjdf asdfioundvklasdvkia
    </div>
</div>
<div id="track">
    <div id="rocket">    
    </div>
</div>
<div id="xpos" style="clear:both">
</div>
<hr>

<div id="textarea">
    <div id="test">

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas eget nisi ipsum. Donec semper, justo at fringilla condimentum, felis tellus ultricies dolor, id convallis metus nulla quis est. Vivamus facilisis orci vel lectus blandit commodo blandit sem tempor. Curabitur condimentum, diam quis pretium feugiat, sem ante pretium tortor, in lobortis massa eros vitae dui. Nullam nisi mauris, condimentum a feugiat in, euismod quis augue. Maecenas euismod adipiscing tellus. Aliquam elementum egestas dolor, vel aliquam nulla tincidunt eget. Etiam risus elit, scelerisque eu volutpat sed, faucibus non ante. Donec sed nunc erat, eget facilisis risus. Etiam id odio tortor. Sed aliquam viverra volutpat. Sed gravida lectus eu mi ornare in feugiat magna elementum. Pellentesque in dolor ligula.

Maecenas condimentum nisl eget arcu elementum nec imperdiet risus lobortis. Suspendisse id placerat turpis. Etiam dolor quam, placerat et volutpat nec, ultricies sed lorem. Fusce volutpat lobortis est ut pellentesque. Donec enim mauris, pretium quis gravida vitae, pellentesque ac nibh. Proin condimentum aliquam scelerisque. Vestibulum aliquet pharetra dapibus. Donec id nisi non nibh fringilla auctor et eget erat. Morbi pretium mauris sed orci pretium aliquam. Nulla pharetra venenatis nunc, in venenatis purus tempor vitae. Vivamus tincidunt dui non eros gravida sit amet consectetur nibh lacinia. 

Maecenas semper ligula et urna tincidunt placerat. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Suspendisse arcu urna, facilisis at tempus id, posuere sed lacus. Vestibulum in feugiat tellus. Nullam suscipit, velit nec tincidunt pellentesque, enim odio ornare mauris, quis faucibus sem sapien sed turpis. Nulla sit amet risus in magna iaculis scelerisque sit amet vel erat. Morbi eu vestibulum nulla. Etiam auctor auctor felis, nec sodales velit condimentum non. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Duis eu massa diam, eu porttitor eros. Etiam blandit, turpis ac volutpat gravida, massa lorem congue orci, eget fringilla eros felis quis elit. Suspendisse quam tellus, pretium non mattis ut, laoreet in diam. Suspendisse ante odio, venenatis vel condimentum vitae, varius id sapien. Quisque ac nunc ipsum. Mauris porttitor blandit magna, id rutrum ipsum pellentesque non. In suscipit diam ligula, non tristique diam.

Aliquam interdum ante at nisl sagittis vel luctus eros fringilla. Vestibulum purus orci, ultrices at tristique et, malesuada eget enim. Praesent commodo erat vel massa auctor id elementum elit elementum. Duis diam urna, mollis ut imperdiet aliquam, commodo id dui. Etiam vulputate facilisis dui id convall

Aliquam interdum ante at nisl sagittis vel luctus eros fringilla. Vestibulum purus orci, ultrices at tristique et, malesuada eget enim. Praesent commodo erat vel massa auctor id elementum elit elementum. Duis diam urna, mollis ut imperdiet aliquam, commodo id dui. Etiam vulputate facilisis dui id convall Daniel 
        asdasdas dasd asd asldnalsdsvlkarau idhlkjansdfnl inaldnflkanlsdfh ]sdf oasdfj ihjaiodfhkajdsnoviaehu234 kn 87r 23n sf8yr 1238u ndkfn9 48yj wodifn2937rh e0o94tjo nug-2jnfio 203nf273rhefn 2893hr0 284f jnf j0nm ;onf9o8h sdjfi9 w8rho jubnr9ygv7gh wionuf2983h iurbgfi9 48hr jfna sdf asdf alsdfn a;sdf kasdfkjasdfnasdfjakjdf asdfioundvklasdvkia
    </div>
</div>
<div id="track">
    <div id="rocket">    
    </div>
</div>
<div id="xpos" style="clear:both">
</div>

​
```

CSS:

```
#textarea{
    height: 400px;
    width: 400px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 10px 0 0 10px;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    float:left;
}
#test{
    height: 400px;
    width: 400px;
    overflow: auto;
}

#track {
    height: 400px;
    width: 48px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 10px 0 0 10px;

    float:left;
}
#rocket{
    height:48px;
    width:48px;
    background: url('http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/Symbolicons_Transportation/48/Rocket.png');

}
​
```

Jquery + Jquery UI:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var lastScrollTop = 0;
    var iHeight = $("#test").height() - 48;
    var iScrollHeight = $("#test").prop("scrollHeight");
    var left = parseInt($('#track').css('margin-left'), 10);
    var top = parseInt($('#track').css('margin-top'), 10);


    var textareaWidth = document.getElementById("test").scrollWidth;

    // width of our wrapper equals width of the inner part of the textarea
    document.getElementById("textarea").style.width = textareaWidth + 'px';

    //common ratio
    var cr = (iScrollHeight / iHeight) - 1.135;
    $("#rocket").css("top", iHeight);

    var draggingRocket = false;
    $("#test").scroll(function(event) {
        if (!draggingRocket) {
            var st = $(this).scrollTop();
            var pos = iHeight - (st / cr);
            $("#rocket").css("top", pos);
        }
    });


    //rocket drag
    $("#rocket").draggable({
        containment: $('#track'),
        axis: "y",
        scroll: false,
        start: function(event, ui) {
            draggingRocket = true;
        },
        drag: function(event, ui) {
            // Show the current dragged position of image
            var currentPos = $(this).position();
            var top = parseInt($('#rocket').css('top'), 10);
            var mst = (iHeight - top) * cr;
            $("#test").scrollTop(mst);

        },
        stop: function(event, ui) {
            draggingRocket = false;
        }
    });

});​
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The attribute id is only valid for one element on the entire page. You have two elements defined "rocket" so your code won't work...

Comment: hey malificent any insight for me to get it working ? like should i enclose it in a parent div and then point it ?

Answer (score 1):

The first error is, that an ID must only occur once per document. You need to implement that feature using class attributes as selector.

Then I would create the `#track`/`#rocket` via JS instead of hardcoding it in the HTML. If you do this right, you only need to assign a specific class to any HTML element and have the scrolling effect enabled and all its elements inserted via the JS event handler.

Example:

```
<div class="my-scroller">
    Content Box 1
</div>

<div class="my-scroller">
    Content Box 2
</div>
```

JS:

```
jQuery( document ).ready( function( $ ) {
    $( '.my-scroller' ).each( function() {

        /* create the scroll handle element (the rocket) */
        var scrollHandle = $( '<div class="scroll-handle rocket" />' );

        /* assign the drag event to the current scroll handle */
        scrollHandle.draggable( /* … */ );

        /* append the scroll handle to the current .my-scroller */
        $( this ).append( scrollHandle );

        /* assign the scroll event to the current .my-scroller */
        $( this ).scroll( /* … */ );

    } );
} );
```

Comment: @Daniel Euchar See answer update (example). The scroll handle (the rocket) is created for and bound to each of the scrolling `DIV` elements.